# PHP Wordpress Cache XML Variable

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, caching

I am currently loading an XML HTTP Request into an array and then caching it although sometimes the site I pull the data from isn't the most reliable and I get back blank page or not everything filled out.  One way of fixing this I thought would to be make sure that the array has the same or more amount of data in the array and then caching it for an hour.  Now here is my issue when ever it array doesn't have the data I don't have the previous cache giving me an error on the cached variable.  Do I know if I understand caching right?  Can I cache a variable and only overwrite if given a certain condition?  Anyhelp would be great.  My thought would be to store the data in mysql and then query it if the variable doesn't go through.
`if ( $checksize>=8 ){
weather_result = wp_cache_get( 'my_result' );

if ( false == $weather_result ) {
    $weather_result= $insert_array;
    wp_cache_add( 'weather_cache', $weather_result,$flag = '',$expire = 0);
} 
}`

Now the checksize is just an array which  counts the number of elements in the array.  I would only like to update this when it has all the information.

Comment: You can cache whatever you want. If you do, you can do whatever you want with the cache. But you should keep caching dead simple.

Comment: Right but when I run the code as  a
if ( $checksize>=8 ) {
$weather_result = wp_cache_get( 'my_result' );
if ( false == $weather_result ) {
 $weather_result= $insert_array;
 wp_cache_add( 'weather_cache', $weather_result,$flag = '',$expire = 3600);
} 
}
and then if it caches once but next time you go to the site if it's not greater than the amount I need it should just run off the previous cache

Comment: Dan, please add that code and comment to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress has an API for caching in database, the transient api. Its eas to use and you can ask for vars, is cached.

```
$tag_cloud = get_transient( 'tag_cloud' );
if ( false === $tag_cloud || '' === $tag_cloud ){
    $args = array('echo' => false);
    $tag_cloud = wp_tag_cloud( $args );
    set_transient( 'tag_cloud', $tag_cloud, 60*60*12 );
}
echo $tag_cloud;
```

see also this [post](http://wpengineer.com/2148/simple-cache-with-the-wordpress-transient-api/) and the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API)

Comment: Right but with this variable I want to only re-cache if a condition is met but if not met keep the previous cache.  Would this work